Enumerate each row for each id
This is my dataframe:
id         url
25         google.com/main
25         google.com/buy
25         google.com/videos
144        google.com/buy
144        google.com/videos
144        google.com/pictures
144        google.com/maps
992        google.com/main
992        google.com/buy

I need to create a new column "row_number" and enumearate each id. I want this:
id         url                   row_number
25         google.com/main       1
25         google.com/buy        2
25         google.com/videos     3
144        google.com/buy        1
144        google.com/videos     2
144        google.com/pictures   3
144        google.com/maps       4
992        google.com/main       1
992        google.com/buy        2   

i was trying:
df['row_number'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(range(1, len(x)+1))).explode()

but it writes an error:
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels


Use df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1

James, thank you it works!
